# Como trabalhar com o plugin 'Camera' de modo a permitir upload de imagem quando em um browser?

Tags: angular, ionic, apache-cordova

Estou tentando implementar um recurso que me permita quando no browser, fazer upload de imagens, já em um dispositivo móvel, terei as opções de tirar uma foto ou escolher uma imagem da galeria.

Tirar um foto ou escolher da galeria já está funcionando nos devices. Mas não estou conseguindo implementar para realizar o upload de imagem quando no browser. Até consigo verificar se o plugin `Camera` está instalada com este trecho:

```
if (!Camera['installed']()) {
  alert('Unable to take photo');
  return false;
}
```

Arquivo ts completo:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera';
import { ActionSheetController, IonicPage, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-add-edit-task',
  templateUrl: 'add-edit-task.html',
})
export class AddEditTaskPage {

  title: string;
  photo: string;

  constructor(public navParams: NavParams, public actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController, private camera: Camera) {
    this.title = (navParams.get('action') == 'edit') ? 'Editar tarefa' : 'Criar tarefa';
  }

  attachPhoto() {

    if (!Camera['installed']()) {
      alert('Unable to take photo');
      return false;
    }

    const actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Tirar foto',
          handler: () => {
            this.cameraOrLibraryPhoto(this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE);
          }
        },{
          text: 'Buscar na galeria',
          handler: () => {
            this.cameraOrLibraryPhoto(this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY, this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE);
          }
        },{
          text: 'Cancelar',
          role: 'cancel'
        }
      ]
    });

    actionSheet.present();
  }

  cameraOrLibraryPhoto(source: number = 1, mediaType: number = 0) {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      mediaType: mediaType,
      sourceType: source,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG
    };

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      this.photo = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
    });
  }
}
```

Arquivo html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>{{ title }}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>Título</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>Nota</ion-label>
      <ion-textarea rows="4"></ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  <button ion-button item-end icon-start color="light" (click)="attachPhoto()">
    <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
    Anexar imagem
  </button>

  <ion-card *ngIf="photo">
    <h2>Previsualização</h2>
    <img src="{{photo}}">
  </ion-card>

  <div padding>
    <button ion-button block>Salvar</button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, não me parece ter sido a melhor alternativa, mas está funcionando. A mágica ocorre basicamente dentro do método `processWebImage`.

Veja o js completo:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera';
import { ActionSheetController, IonicPage, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-add-edit-task',
  templateUrl: 'add-edit-task.html',
})
export class AddEditTaskPage {

  @ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput;

  title: string;
  photo: string;

  constructor(public navParams: NavParams, private actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController, private camera: Camera) {
    this.title = (navParams.get('action') == 'edit') ? 'Editar tarefa' : 'Criar tarefa';
  }

  attachPhoto() {
    if (!Camera['installed']()) {
      this.fileInput.nativeElement.click();
      return false;
    }

    const actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Tirar foto',
          handler: () => {
            this.cameraOrLibraryPhoto(this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE);
          }
        },{
          text: 'Buscar na galeria',
          handler: () => {
            this.cameraOrLibraryPhoto(this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY, this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE);
          }
        },{
          text: 'Cancelar',
          role: 'cancel'
        }
      ]
    });
    actionSheet.present();
  }

  processWebImage(event) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (readerEvent) => {
      let imageData = (readerEvent.target as any).result;
      this.photo =  imageData;
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
  }

  cameraOrLibraryPhoto(source: number = 1, mediaType: number = 0) {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      mediaType: mediaType,
      sourceType: source,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG
    };

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      this.photo = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
    });
  }
}
```

No arquivo HTML:

```
<input type="file" #fileInput style="visibility: hidden; height: 0px" class="file-input" name="files[]" (change)="processWebImage($event)" accept="image/*">
```